# It's impossible to operate with state after installed package react

Tags: reactjs, state

I have react application and for display photo slider i installed `tiny-slider-react` package,
i installed it and configured it works fine till i try to do something with state even when i try to do something like this:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(23)
  },
[])
```

this error i get each time [image]

i cannot void using state. Please how can i figure out what is happening and how can i solve it ?

UPD:

```
 <BackgroundLayer theme="lightPink2">
  <PageContent paddingTop marginTop>
    <Chapter title={title} description={description} className="logos" />
    <div className="is-mobile is-hidden-desktop is-hidden-tablet">
      <TinySlider settings={settings} onTouchMove={(event) => setIndex(event.index)}>
        {renderLogos(logos, "slider-padding", "slider__image")}
      </TinySlider>
      <div className="squares">
        {aaaaaaa.map(a => (
          <div key={guuid()} className={a.val} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  </PageContent>
</BackgroundLayer>
```

UDP2 Settings:

```
const settings = {
  nav: false,
  mouseDrag: true,
  controls: false,
  loop: false,
  }
```

UPD3:That's how RenderLogos method looks like

```
  const renderLogos = (logos, firstClass, secondClass) => {
   return (
    <>
      {logos.map(s => (
        <div key={guuid()} className={firstClass}>
          {s.map(({ logo: { title, file: { url } } }) => (
            <Logo
              url={url}
              title={title}
              key={guuid()}
              styleClass={secondClass}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: can you show us the code where you use tiny-slider-react?

Comment: @tudor.gergely done

Comment: what is settings? and what is renderLogos? can you add the code for those as well?

Comment: @tudor.gergely added UDP 2

Comment: what about renderLogos? how does that look?

Comment: @tudor.gergely thanks for don't give up and trying to help me, UPD3

Comment: @tudor.gergely problem disappears when i remove <TinySlider ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are rendering a React.Fragment (1 element) while the library assumes you will render multiple elements as children for TinySlider.

Try changing renderLogos to this:

```
const renderLogos = (logos, firstClass, secondClass) => {
  // render a list directly, not a list inside a fragment
  return logos.map((s) => (
    <div key={guuid()} className={firstClass}>
      {s.map(({ logo: { title, file: { url } } }) => (
        <Logo url={url} title={title} key={guuid()} styleClass={secondClass} />
      ))}
    </div>
  ));
};
```